# React-select collapse items that do not fit into the container

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

React-select. Group all items that do not fit into the container with multiple selections. All elements that do not fit collapse into one - "...". Do it dynamically when onResize.

I tried to rewrite the react-select components, but there were some difficulties

Example:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try grids..

The documentation is pretty clear and concise.

grid-row
grid-col

Add number after and follow css syntax.